# How to avoid calling web api in loops?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I have two web api’s

1. **Publish API -** copies the data from one database to another database . It usually takes 10-15 mins to complete the process.
2. **GetStatus API -** fetch the status of publish API. The valid status are Running, Failed and Completed.

Now, I am calling the **Publish API** And then in loop I am calling **GetStatus API** and the server is loaded with too many requests for **GetStatus API**. For every 10-15 milliseconds the GetStatus api is being called.

How to avoid this? Any better solution should be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Now, I will call the publish API And then in loop I will call GetStatus API in loop and the server is loaded with too many GetStatus request." - what?!?

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Well... you should just wait in the loop...

Ideally you are using async so you can do:

```
ApiStatus status = null;
do {
    var status = await api.GetStatus();
    await Task.Deplay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
  
} while (status == ApiStatus.Running);
```

or if not something like;

```
while (!_stopEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)){
    var status = api.GetStatus();
    if (status != ApiStatus.Running) break;
}
```

At the very least, naive implementation which you shouldn't actually do, but to show you simplest case...

```
while (true){
    var status = api.GetStatus();
    if (status != ApiStatus.Running) break;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Async keyword is missing. Why we are using await keyword only. Please enlighten me

Comment: I just said ideally you are using async. If you are not, use the second option instead. You can read about async here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async